# Delayed moving average

Tags: qgis, python

I want to develop a plot of delayed moving average. The code for this in MATLAB is:

```
nr_pontos = 36;
coefs_filtro = ones(1, nr_pontos)/nr_pontos;
data_dma = filter(coefs_filtro, 1, data);
figure,plot(data)
hold on,plot(data_dma,'r')
hold off
```

But I want to develop this in python using numpy or scipy.
I found the convolve function of numpy, but I think the results were not what I expected. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Could you clarify how this question relates to GIS? Currently, it seems like it might be better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: Hello. This code is implemented in a gis application.